# Regular expression for youtube url

Tags: c#, asp.net

what is the regular expression for a url ? 
in my web application i want to validate url when the user enters the url in textbox.

url like: http://www.youtube.com/embed/OWj0fns95xw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/
```

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know/

Answer (score 1):

(http(s)?://)?([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ;,./?%&=]*)?

It's work.

Comment: It doesnt work!